# Karma/Jasmine/PhantomJs: undefined is not a constructor

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, yeoman, karma-jasmine

I have an application that raise an odd error when I run tests. The error is the following :

```
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'allKeys[i].match(/^[0-9]+$/)') in node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js (line 2988)
test/spec/core/http/response-spec.js:92:63
loaded@http://localhost:8080/context.js:151:17
```

Most of those tests passes, but a very few break. Here is one of the test that breaks:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  describe('MyAccount.core.http.response', function () {
    var ResponseInterceptor = {},
        $httpProvider = {},
        $window = {},
        env = {},
        MessageQueue = {};

    beforeEach(module('MyAccount.core.environment'));
    beforeEach(module('MyAccount.core.http', function (_$httpProvider_, $provide) {
      $httpProvider = _$httpProvider_;

      MessageQueue  = {
        dispatch: jasmine.createSpy('dispatch')
      };

      $window = {
        location: {
          href: jasmine.createSpy()
        }
      };

      $provide.value('$window', $window);
      $provide.value('MessageQueue', MessageQueue);
    }));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$window_, _ResponseInterceptor_, _env_) {
      $window = _$window_;
      ResponseInterceptor = _ResponseInterceptor_;
      env = _env_;
    }));

    describe('response status', function () {
      // Asserting that 404 and 403 errors are intercepted.
      angular.forEach([404, 403], function (error) {
        describe('is ' + error, function () {
          beforeEach(function () {
            ResponseInterceptor.responseError({
              status: error,
              data: {
                message: 'error ' + error
              }
            });
          });

          it('calls MessageQueue.dispatch with the error message', function () {
            expect(MessageQueue.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('error ' + error, {
              on: 'global.errors'
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
})();
```

I've been stuck on that for few hours now and can't seems to find a solution. Here are the dependencies I'm using and their versions:

- karma: `^1.2.0`
- jasmine-core: `^2.5.0`
- karma-jasmine: `^1.0.2`
- karma-phantomjs-launcher: `^1.0.2`
- phantomjs: `^2.1.7`

NOTE: This is a brand new `yeoman` application using the angular generator.

Comment: You're not the only one, I got the same issue this week, and I'm currently debugging it.

In my case, I'm using Maven/frontend-maven-plugin/Jasmine-Core/PhantomJS

What I have found so far, in my case: It is the equal arrays that fail. Yes, the equal arrays! If the arrays have differences, the test fails the regular way ( ["a", 12] does not equal ["b", 56] ).

But everything works if I'm running Karma manually in IntelliJ. It doesn't use the same Jasmine Core (deleting Jasmine-Core used by Maven didn't prevent manual run), so I think Jasmine-Core is the culprit.

Comment: Could you please confirm that equal arrays are the ones that is failing in yours?

Comment: @Darth_Sygnious I have the same issue with the array. Failing normally when comparing with something else. I'll try to downgrade/upgrade JasmineCore in order to see if this is a possible cause of the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, but got it solved moments ago.

To repeat what I said in the comments: The error happens when you have two arrays that are **equal**, believe it or not. If they are unequal, you get the standard error with the differences shown.

jasmine-core 2.5.0. was published two days ago, as of this moment. I downgraded to 2.4.1., and it works.

It seems that 2.5.0. is the culprit.

Downgrade to 2.4.1., until the publisher gets it solved.

My setup: maven/frontend-maven-plugin/karma(*)/phantomJS

(*) could probably have said 'Jasmine' here as well.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, downgrade could be the solution. You solved my problem man, can't thank you enough :)

Comment: [Jasmine 2.5.1](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/release_notes/2.5.1.md), released Sept 9 2016, fixes this issue.