# Ionic2 + Karma + Jasmine: Undefined is not a constructor

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, ionic2, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to make some tests for and Ionic2 App with Karma + Jasmine, but got stuck due to a runtime error and I can't determine which is the actual problem (probably my lack of experience).

## My environment:

### test.ts

A really simple class with a bare constructor and a dummy function:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-testing',
  templateUrl: 'testing.html'
})

export class TestingPage {
  
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
  
  isTrue(): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}
```

#### test.spec.ts

```
import { TestingPage } from "./test.ts"
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

let navCtrl: NavController;
let test = new TestingPage(navCtrl);

describe('Dummy test:', () => {
  it("Should be defined", () => {
    expect(test.isTrue()).toBeTruthy(); 
  });
});
```

#### karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'karma-typescript'],
    files: [
      //'./src/pages/testing/test.ts',
      './src/pages/testing/test.spec.ts'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      //'./src/pages/testing/test.ts': ['karma-typescript'],          
      './src/pages/testing/test.spec.ts': ['karma-typescript']
    },

    typescriptPreprocessor: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: false,
        target: 'ES5',
        module: 'amd',
        noImplicitAny: true,
        noResolve: true,
        removeComments: true,
        concatenateOutput: false
      },
      transformPath: function(path) {
        return path.replace(/\.ts$/, '.js');
      }
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'karma-typescript'],
    port: 9876,  
    colors: true,   
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,   
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

#### Some extra info, just in case it's relevant...

```
Ionic version: 2.1.13
Karma version: 1.3.0
TypeScript: 2.0.6
jasmine-core: 2.4.1
```

The error when running `karma start` is:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new test_ts_1.TestingPage(navCtrl)')
  at src/pages/testing/test.spec.ts:5:0 <- src/pages/testing/test.spec.js:4


Chrome 54.0.2840 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught TypeError: test_ts_1.TestingPage is not a constructor
  at src/pages/testing/test.spec.ts:5:0 <- src/pages/testing/test.spec.js:4
```

I've tried to include the test.ts in karma files, and preprocessors section (they are commented in the karma.conf.js above), but in that case the error changes to:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Map
  at /tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-2311r0Dc9vytYCw1.js:5007


Chrome 54.0.2840 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__symbol__' of undefined
  at /tmp/karma-typescript-bundle-2311r0Dc9vytYCw1.js:26028
```

which seems even less descriptive.

Adittionally Jasmine was also downgraded from 2.5.X after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288777/karma-jasmine-phantomjs-undefined-is-not-a-constructor) (error still occurs)

#### EDIT:

performing tests like

```
expect(2+2).toEqual(4);
```

without importing any class, works fine.

Any ideas about what is missing or wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to write `from "./test"` instead of `from "./test.ts"`?

Comment: You aren't creating a navctrl thus its undefined. You need to create a mock class to mock the navctrl so then you can inject it in to your controller. Here's your example https://github.com/lathonez/clicker/blob/master/src/mocks.ts

Comment: @yurzui, removing the ".ts" tailing leads to a "not found module" error.
@misha130, thanks for the correction, that was missing too, but when creating the NavMock object the error occurs agains. Basically I'm unable to create any `let any = new MyClass()` because of the "undefined is not a constructor", so maybe the problem is related to karma conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved, I had multiple mistaskes in my configuration + code.

Just as @misha130 commented, a mock is needed for the navCtrl.

In karma.conf.js **the order of importing the files is relevant**, also had to add the mock class to files and preprocessor properties.

And last and more important, as @yurziu said, when importing a module don't add '.ts' as tailing because if karma transpiles the .ts to .js you will still import the TS file instead of the JS.

---

Aditionally I needed to add polyfills to make the transpiler *understand* all angular2 decorators (@Component, @ViewChild, etc). For this I used [this](https://github.com/lathonez/clicker/blob/master/src/polyfills.ts) example. And added the polyfills to karma.conf.js.

```
files: [
    './src/polyfills.ts',
    './src/mocks.ts', //this must be imported before test.ts!
    './src/pages/testing/test.ts',
    './src/pages/testing/test.spec.ts'
],

preprocessors: {     
    './src/polyfills.ts': ['karma-typescript'],            
    './src/mocks.ts': ['karma-typescript'], //and also preprocessed
    './src/pages/home/home.ts': ['karma-typescript'],      
    './src/pages/home/home.spec.ts': ['karma-typescript']
}
```

Hope this helps someone.